# Opening/Activating Word Documents in a VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm hoping a VB/VBA expert can help me out.  Consider the following:
    The user opens a document in Word 2003, and within the Normal.dot `AutoOpen` macro, we look at current document, and if it has been opened by clicking on a link on a webpage, and meets certain other application specific criteria, close the streamed 'copy' and open the source document (found on a shared drive we can assume the user has access to):

```
Documents.Open origDoc
Documents(ActiveDocument.FullName).Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Documents(origDoc).Activate

With ActiveDocument
    ''# Do work
End With
```

My thought was that I needed to call `Activate` to ensure that the original document was the `ActiveDocument`, but I'm getting a 4160 'Bad file name' error on the `.Activate` call.  If I comment out the call to `.Activate`, it appears that `ActiveDocument` is set to the origDoc  document, even if there were other documents already opened (I'm not really sure how the Documents Collection is managed, and how Word determines what next `ActiveDocument` would be if you programatically close the current ActiveDocument)

So, does calling `.Open` on a document explicitly set the Document to be the `ActiveDocument`?  Also, does calling `.Activate` on the already active document cause an error?

I haven't really been able to find much documentation about this, so thanks in advance for any suggestions and insight!

Comment: Presumably you've been handling the streamed copy of the document as the ActiveDocument in your code. It would be much better to assign that document object to a variable at the begining of your code and use your variable through the rest of the code. As other's have pointed out, you are likely closing the wrong version of the document in the second line of code. Also it would be wise to assign the "original" document object to a variable when you open it.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is yes. By opening the document with your code you make it the active document, which you then close in the next line and try to activate in the next, and this fails because the document is no longer open. VBA in general seems to work this way.

It is important to be careful with ActiveDocument, because it's not always self-evident what actions, in code or elsewhere, will make a document 'active' (i have no proof but even an autosave might do it). IF there's any doubt you're better off referring to a document through the Documents collection, though this can also cause errors if the document is no longer open, and you might have to resort to iterating through the collection to be sure the document is, in fact, open. I run into this a lot with excel VBA, and Word VBA seems to function identically in that regard.

Also, VBA is flaky about releasing application objects. If you're not careful you'll end up with multiple WINWORD processes,viewable in task manager, regardless of whether you Close or Quit them in your code. The code I've found to work around this amounts to simulating the process of selecting END PROCESS in task manager. It works, but there should be a better solution.

Comment: VBA? Flaky? Why I've never heard such accusations!

Answer (score 2):

Beware that there are a variety of problems that can be encountered:

1. if you want to re-open the document after closing it
   once....Word/Windows DOES NOT
       'release' the filename and you get a '*file busy*' message, or message about *'creating 
        a temporary copy*'.
       to deal with this problem, I've had to develop an elaborate system of creating/saving and 
       tidying up multiple versions of any other documents I open/manipulate in my Word applications
       because of this design flaw in Office `Open`/`Close`/`Save` methods.
2. Use the `ReadOnlyRecommended` property set to `False` with the
   `.Open` method
3. referring to the document object (named doc, above) can cause
   serious errors if you do not assure
       that the `doc` object still exists before you try and manipulate it.  Remember always, that
       Word is an 'open' application platform....and the user can be doing things you didn't count
       on...in the last millisecond or so. This advice holds for any other object or property you may
       wish to manipulate in Word.
4. if you manipulate the Documents collection (or any other) without
   assuring that the document or    other object is still there and
   valid before deleting or moving it within the collection you may
   get '*stack overflow*' errors. Particularly if you try and
   close/delete objects in a collection     starting at `.item(1)`.  You
   must delete items in a collection from the last one, and remember
   that    the collection idicies and pointers change whenever you
   .add/.remove/.close items from them.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here:

```
Document(origDoc).Activate
```

Should be Document**s**.

Yes, you can activate the active document. Nothing happens then.

Yes, opened document becomes active.
If you are not sure, use `Documents.Open(origDoc).Activate`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo, unfortunately it was only in my post, not the actual code.  If you are allowed to activate the open document, then how come I am getting a 4160 error on the .Activate call?

Comment: What exactly does origDoc contain?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the `ActiveDocument` object in the first place unless absolutely necessary because it's very unreliable. The preferred approach would be this:

```
Documents(ActiveDocument.FullName).Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

Dim doc as Document
Set doc = Documents.Open(origDoc)        
With doc
    'Do work
End With
```

Comment: I am obviously missing something here.  You say to not use `ActiveDocument`, but you go ahead and use it in your code sample?